# How to serialize partial classes with WebAPI and Linq

Tags: c#, jquery, linq, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I am using LINQ to SQL to generate classes. I want to write some partial classes to extend their functionality. I later use these classes as return objects from my controllers in WEBAPI. The issue is that I cannot get the members that I have added in my partial classs in jquery. Other elements that are generated by LINQ come correctly.
I guess this has to do something with serialization. I put [Serializable] attribute over my partial class but it did not work...

Some code snippets for elaboration:
Classes generated by LINQ are like:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Categories")]
[global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
public partial class Category : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_CategoryID",      AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="BigInt NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true,     IsDbGenerated=true, UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
    [global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Order=1)]
    public long CategoryID
    {
    }
}
```

And my class is like:

```
[Serializable]
public partial class Category
{
    public string CoverImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

I get CategoryID in response in JQUERY on response by controllers. But I do not get CoverImageUrl. Please help me sort this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try to use the datacontract attributes that the generated code uses

```
public partial class Category
{
    [DataMember]
    public string CoverImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the CoverImageUrl with the attribute DataMember.